# Tomcat7 -> Tomcat8 - Server just prints half of the html page

Tags: html, apache, tomcat, tomcat7, tomcat8

I have a very weird problem:

I upgraded from Tomcat 7 and Java 7 to Tomcat 8 and Java 8.
The webapp is called ROOT.war, so that the servlet "Index" gets activated.

When I go to www.myurl.com, the server just prints half of the html page, but when I go to www.myurl.com/Index, it print the full page. But this is the same Servlet, very weird! In Tomcat 7 and Java 7 it worked without problem.

The code where it breaks is just text:

```
            "                            <br />\r\n" + 
            "                            <br />\r\n" + 
            "                            <font size=\"2\" color=\"#000000\"><b>just text 1.\r\n" + 
            "                            just text 2.</b></font>\r\n" + 
            "                            <br />\r\n" +
```

In my browser "just text 1." is the last line, but there should be 200more lines.

Does someone has a idea? This is so weird because the same servlet works with www.myurl.com/Index and not with www.myurl.com.

Comment: is there any output on the console / catalina.out ? Can you show more code from the servlet (how are you writing the output e.g. response.getWriter().write....) ?  Perhaps also post `conf/server.xml`?

Comment: thanks for your answer. Maybe this is the reason: When you go to www.myurl.com it opens index.jsp, which cotains "<jsp:forward page="/Index" />" and opens Index.java.

I dont know how to open Index.java without the .jsp. Dint work when I write Index.java in the web.xml welcome file

Comment: no output in console and it is out.println("..."). server.xml is stock expect for the port 8080->80 and the host localhost->www.myurl.com

Comment: ok it was because of the jsp. I replaced the jsp with a html with forwarding to Index and it works. But I dont know why the jsp worked in tomcat7 but not in 8 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not saying what version of Tomcat you use.

There is a bug in 8.0.17 that causes responses after `<jsp:forward>` to be truncated. It was noted a day after release. ([link 1](http://tomcat.markmail.org/thread/bdmlix6ec2fhfarc), [link 2](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57476))

Comment: Thanks a lot! I use 8.0.17, its still new newest version.

I use a html file instead of the .jsp now and it workes fine. Is there any disadvantage (performance) using html instead of jsp.

And there is another problem, maybe you know why:
special signs like ä,ü,ö worked fine in tomcat7, but in tomcat8 its "?". why?